# Odd iCloud syncing issue

Tags: icloud, windows

Having problems with photos syncing from iPhone 5s to PC running Windows 7. Long story short, my wife's photos sync to her computer, mine only syncs to 1 of 3 computers (all Win 7 Pro) all on the same wifi network at home. As mentioned, no problems on 1 of our computers with the photos populating within seconds of taking them. On the 2 that will not show them, I can only get iCloud to show "My Photo Stream" and "Activity" folders when clicking the "iCloud Photos" shortcut link in favorites when opening Windows Explorer

[image: image1]

On the computer that does bring the photo from the cloud, I set it up to save them to a network drive and if I point the non-working pc's to that folder as default for iCloud, I still see nothing on my computer when double clicking "My Photo Stream"

[image: image2]

Here's the kicker: if I click the "Open Folder" link in the above photo, the folder opens correctly and shows the files

[image: image3]

Does anyone have any clues why these photos in the linked default iCloud folder are not showing on 2 of my computers? I've tried for many hours to figure this out and would appreciate any suggestions beyond the normal "reset iCloud" - "sign out then sign back in" - "delete account from phone and reload it" answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is genuinely because of multiple iCloud accounts used on one PC. Just for the sake of experiment, try installing iCloud on a PC where no other iCloud have ever been installed. I am sure, it will sync with it, and it is certainly a cache problem.

Secondly, regarding the My Photo Stream not showing up anything but you can still see 3 photos when you click open folder ... this is because Photo Stream shows photos when its a collection or multiple of 5 photos (e.g 5, 10, 15, 20), so if you have 5 photos in the folder, it will show up, then it won't show until it get 10 (in case of total photos <> multiple of 5, it will come up with all photos it has, as the last photo will tell that this is the end of the album). Make sure it is not a network drive, as iCloud doesn't re-download photos once it is interrupted.